# JSRender - Group based on property

Tags: jsrender

I have a JSON array that looks like this:

```
[{ Title: "Bing", Url: "bing.com", Category: "CAT1 }, { Title: "MSDN", Url: "msdn.com",
Category: "CAT1 }, { Title: "Pinterest", Url: "pinterest.com", Category: "CAT2" }];
```

I want to create a render template that groups these:

```
<div>CAT1</div>
<div>Bing</div>
<div>MSDN</div>

<div>CAT2</div>
<div>Pinterest</div>
```

I think if my JSON was nested it would be easier but that's not the case here. I appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to sort your array first (or clone it then sort the clone) so it is sorted by Category.

Now iterate over the sorted array:

```
{{for mySortedArray ~array=mySortedArray}}
    {{if !#index || ~array[#index-1].Category !== Category}} 
        <div>{{:Category}}</div>
    {{/if}}
    <div>{{:Title}}</div>
{{/for}}
```